# Checking whether two tables have the same number of rows never finishes. What's wrong with this query?

Tags: sqlite

I'm using SQLite 3.39.3.

I came up with this query to check whether two tables have the same number of rows:

```
SELECT COUNT(a.auth_id)=COUNT(b.auth_scopus_id) FROM auth_subject_areas_mapping AS a, auth_subject_areas_mapping_old AS b;
```

But the query never finishes.
`EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN` gives me:

[image]

Questions:

1. What's wrong with my query?
2. What is the correct way in SQLite to check whether two tables have the same number of rows?

Comment: What are you trying to do here? This query will always return true as its cross-join.

Comment: I'm trying to check whether two tables have the same number of rows. What does it mean "its cross-join"?

Comment: Dont think this is the correct way to check after results are crossed both sets will have same number of records always. Should use something like ```select 
(select count(A.id) from A) =
(select count(B.id) from B) chk_cnt```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
WITH
    acount AS (SELECT count(*) AS a FROM auth_subject_areas_mapping),
    bcount AS (SELECT count(*) AS b FROM auth_subject_areas_mapping_old)
SELECT a = b FROM acount, bcount;
```

Comment: You need to count rows in each table first, than join the results, not the other way around.

Comment: Why I'm joining the results before counting rows? I do not understand.

Comment: This is `FROM auth_subject_areas_mapping AS a, auth_subject_areas_mapping_old AS b` a join operation. Basically, you ask SQLite to create a joined table and then both COUNT(a.auth_id) and COUNT(b.auth_scopus_id) will count rows in the joined table, which is always true. But SQLite may need to build this table first. Either way, the result is meaningless and may take some time to calculate. `a.auth_id` and `b.auth_scopus_id` refer to columns in the joined table, not original tables.